# SoapUI- Is it possible to create a Mock service from a sample oData call?

Tags: odata, soapui

Is it possible to create a Mock Service from a sample oData call in soapui?
(without WSDL)

Comment: What did you try already? Seems more a question for google than StackOverflow. Read the instructions for creating a good question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

you can try below sample:

http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/rest-sample-project.html

cheers...